# Is it possible to create a firmlink on the latest version of macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, apfs

`synthetic.conf` creates empty, mountable directories and symlinks, not firmlinks.

While I do know you can create another volume inside the APFS container and use `synthetic.conf` to provide me with a mountpoint, this is not what this question is about. I'm wondering about the "real deal".